# jboss standalone.xml logger category to different file

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I want to configure jboss 7 to save two categories in different file, but this file sql_hib.log is empty when i start jboss.
FILE_SQL handler doesn't working. I don't know why...
If i place FILE_SQL to root loggers - then sql_hib.log starts to grow, but in that case it contains a lot of redundant logs.
That is the part of standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                ...
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                ...
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_SQL" autoflush="true">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="sql_hib.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>


            <logger category="org.hibernate.sql">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.hibernate">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="TRACE"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: Do you see `org.hibernate.sql` trace log entries in the the `server.log`?

Comment: It is strange, because this settings just start working. And yes - i see 'org.hibernate.sql' trace log in the 'server.log'. I post my result settings below

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very old thread. But it might help someone. use-parent-handlers will do the trick. In this case, it won't print duplicated log through root-logger.

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_SQL" autoflush="true">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="sql_hib.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
<logger category="org.hibernate.SQL" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made this setting to debug sql queries and parameters.
That's why i've decided to use separate file. Also i made more categories, because one class is making too much text. `AbstractResultSetProxyHandler`
As i mentioned before - settings just starts working... I change them a bit - to avoid ocean unnecessary text.
Result settings:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_SQL" autoflush="true">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="sql_hib.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.type">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.loader">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.persister">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.hql">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.cfg">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.dialect">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.service">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyHandler">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE_SQL"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

I know that it's better to filter just one `AbstractResultSetProxyHandler` than i place every other category to settings. But i don't know how to filter.
And that settings works.
But hibernate logs are written in `server.log` too. I don't understand why

Comment: Hi, it past so much time, but I have the same problem. My new file is created, but nothin is written there, just only in server.log. Maybe, you remember how to divide that two files?